aspnetboilerplate InvalidOperationException
Downloaded latest stable version of aspnetboilerplate,

Installed client libraries using libman.json restore,
getting following strange errors on very first build

InvalidOperationException
Expected Identifier


System.InvalidOperationException: No file exists for the asset at either location 'wwwroot\view-resources\Views\Account\Login.min.js' or 'wwwroot\view-resources\Views\Account\Login.min.js'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticWebAssets.Tasks.StaticWebAsset.ComputeFingerprintAndIntegrity(String identity, String originalItemSpec)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticWebAssets.Tasks.DefineStaticWebAssets.Execute()

Expected identifier: . \wwwroot\view-resources\Views\_Bundles\shared-layout.min.js

Expected expression: . \wwwroot\view-resources\Views\_Bundles\shared-layout.min.js

actually wwwroot\view-resources\Views\Account\Login.min.js this file exists
